# Using the Heroku web interface, how do you export a PG database from Heroku into a CSV file?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, postgresql, heroku, export-to-csv

I am trying to export a CSV file from Heroku's PostGresql database to import it into a MongoDB outside of Heroku.  Does anyone know of any good way of exporting a CSV file from directly from the Heroku website?
The question is asking how to export a CSV file using Heroku's web interface, not the command line interface.

Comment: ctshryock's answer is exactly what I was looking for.  The question you are referring to shows a slightly more complicated way since it is not linked directly to Heroku.  But thanks anyways!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can export a csv of a single table using dataclips: https://dataclips.heroku.com

To export the entire database like this you would need to do this one table at a time

Comment: great - works very well!